# How do I also include the Bootstrap fonts directory in my ASP app?

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm running ASP5 / MVC6.

I'm including Bootstrap through bower, like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />`

When running my app, code snippets that utilize the glyphicons fonts do not work, such as this:

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>`

It simply shows an empty rectangle.

If I use Chrome to debug my app, I can see that the fonts are not included in the Sources tab of the debugger... so how can I include those fonts from within my website?

**Edit:**

My bootstrap.css is default, so it has:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

And my directory structure matches this:

[image: bootstrap-dir]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. My site's CSS file had this applied in it:

`h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div, span, li, a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important; }`

This was overriding the font family of the span element, which is what glyphicons use.

Answer (score 0):

Change your bootstrap.css, and make sure the fontface src is pointing to the proper directory:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Please see my latest edit. Everything default should be correct, as my image indicates.

Comment: Note, even if I point to Bootstrap's cdn, the fonts are still not coming along with it... so I'm not sure what to do from here. Still researching.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you place the `font` folder directly under the project root and not nested inside bootstrap => dist folders.

This part `'../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')` in your CSS is trying to read the fonts from the root directory, But you don't have one in the root directory.  Moving the folder as mentioned above should fix the issue.

Comment: That's not true. ASP5 will keep the structure of the relative directories to each package, and pull in assets that are needed as they're referenced. Regardless, if I point to the CDN for Bootstrap, fonts are still not coming along with it - so there's something else going on here perhaps?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion??

Comment: Your suggestion is not correct. `../fonts/` does not point to the root of an application, it's points to the relative directory of the css file.

Comment: I have faced such issues and I have fixed it this way. Give it a try if you don't mind.. It's just matter of dragging out the folder in your solution explorer.

Comment: @mariocatch are you getting any error in your console?? You must be getting 500 error.. Just check

Comment: No errors at all. I'm going to try and repro this in a new asp5/mvc6 project.